# Image in HTML won't respond to CSS

Tags: html, css, image

I have an image that I'm using for the top of a site, and it is currently a square, but I would like it to be circular. I created a CSS class, but the image won't respond to it. I have the image linked correctly (it appears in the site, and responds to HTML; my CSS also links and works for everything but the image.) Both the HTML and CSS both validate as well, and I can't find a solution.

```css
.circular {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<img class="circular" src="http://placehold.it/200x200" alt="placeholder image" title="placeholder image" height="200" width="200">
```

I also tried writing my CSS as `img.circular{ border-radius: 50%;}`but that didn't work either for some reason.

Comment: The example works, what browser are you using?

Comment: @Roberrrt I am using Chrome, and running it from Notepad++. From what I see, it should work, but I can't get it to

Comment: Tested in chrome, mozilla, and internet explorer all work as expected.

Comment: @Scath do you believe it could be because I'm running it from Notepad++ then?

Comment: Nothing to do with notepad++. You can try to hard-refresh to see if that does anything. Maybe add `overflow: hidden` as well to the class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sometimes you have to refresh your css file.. 
If you look at the source is the entry visable?

Comment: that fixed it, closed all files and reopened them all and re-did the class

Answer (score 1):

Try this: right click the image in Chrome and select 'inspect'. This should then open the Chrome Developer tools. You `img` element should be automatically selected.

From here, using the 'styles' and 'computed' tabs you can inspect what styles are currently active on your element in question. You can then verify if your styles are present and see if some other styles are overruling them. E.g.

```
#somethingElse .circular{
    border-radius: 0%;
}

.circular {
    border-radius: 50%;//this will have no effect due to selector weighting
}
```

And furthermore

```
.circular {
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.circular {
    border-radius: 0%;//this will overwrite the earlier property
}
```

Answer (score 1):

While you make changes to a static site files locally, is better to disable cache in your browser.

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd> to open **Developer Tools**, navigate to **Network** tab and select **Disable cache**.

As long as the Developer Tools is open, cache will be disabled.

Don't forget to refresh the page in your browser after you save your changes in your editor.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be working.  What problem are you having?

```css
.circular {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<img class="circular" src="https://i.imgur.com/KyrfT4U.jpg" alt="placeholder image" title="placeholder image" height="200" width="200">
```

Comment: It was working on everything but my computer. I hard refreshed notepad and added the class back and now it is working fine. Must've been a little bug or something.